# Comparisons in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a program that checks whether the number stored in a file (variable n) + 8 is greater or equal to 100. If it is, terminate, else, add 8 and store back in file. However, when I try running it, it says the command in line 4 (if condition) cannot be found. Can someone please explain to me why this isn't working? Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$(cat test.txt)
if [$(($n+8)) -ge 100]
then
    echo 'terminated program' > test.txt
else
    m=$(($n+3))
    echo $m > test.txt
fi
```

Comment: You can use `n=$(<test.txt)` which is a bash builtin way to avoid spawning a cat process.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have identified this issue automatically.

Comment: You might want to `declare -i n=$(<test.txt)` that offers some protection in case the file contains non-numbers (somehow)

Comment: If the file is only supposed to contain a single number on one line, just use `read n < test.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You miss some spaces :

```
if [$(($n+8)) -ge 100]
```

->

```
if [ $(($n+8)) -ge 100 ]
```

But while using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), prefer a modern solution, using [*bash arithmetic*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) :

```
if (( n+8 >= 100 ))
```

or even

```
if ((n+8>=100))
```

Like @Gordon Davisson said in comments : *arithmetic contexts like inside (( )) are one of the few places in bash where spaces aren't critical delimiters.*

Comment: Thanks! forgot spacing matters in bash.

Comment: Right. `[` is actually a **command**. See `help [` at a bash prompt. And like any command, it needs spaces to separate it from its arguments. Keep in mind that the next word after `if` is a command.

Comment: Note: arithmetic contexts like inside `(( ))` are one of the few places in bash where spaces aren't critical delimiters.